# Getting hexadecimal value as branch name in git

Tags: git

I cloned a repo from github and when I opened it using gitbash in local machine I am getting some hexadecimal value as branch name, I was expecting it to be master but it is not.
[image]

Comment: Just checkout an existing branch, your `HEAD` is currently pointing at a commit directly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+what+is+detached+HEAD